# Como utilizar a biblioteca keyboard?

Tags: python-2.7, teclado

Como utilizar o keyboard para realizar uma atividade caso seja pressionada determinada tecla? Em minhas pesquisas, não consegui achar algum exemplo nesse molde:

```
import keyboard

b = 0
if keyboard.press('b'): #sei que o certo não é utilizar o press, mas, o que boto no lugar?
    b = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma Lib de automação com Python, por exemplo:
 pyautogui(Python2) - https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html 
 ou  
pywinauto(Python3) - https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Em python3 você poderia fazer isso:

```
from pywinauto.keyboard import SendKeys, KeySequenceError

try:
    SendKeys({ESC})
except Exception as exception:
    print str(exception)
```

Answer (score -1):

se voce quer usar a biblioteca keyboard para isso tenho esse script aqui se quiser.

no primeiro se voce pressiona a tecla ele vai ficar se repetindo enquanto voce estiver pressionando a tecla

```
import keyboard


def main():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            print("a")
        if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
            print("b")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

mas se quer clicar so uma vez tambem tem esse:

```
import keyboard

def main():
    a_pressed = False
    w_pressed = False

    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('a') and not a_pressed:
            print("geleia")
            a_pressed = True
        elif not keyboard.is_pressed('a') and a_pressed:
            a_pressed = False

        if keyboard.is_pressed('w') and not w_pressed:
            print("arroz")
            w_pressed = True
        elif not keyboard.is_pressed('w') and w_pressed:
            w_pressed = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

a partir dai se ja da um jeito

Comment: Veja nas tags que a pergunta é especifica para Python 2.7 e o código da sua resposta funciona apenas com Python 3 ou superior. Favor [edit] a resposta e adequar o código aos requisitos da pergunta.